# How does this tensegrity structure work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, equilibrium

[image]

How does this structure work? Where is the centre of gravity in this case?

Comment: Do you understand that the center of mass of a system can be in space rather than inside matter?

Comment: yes I understand that the centre of gravity can be in space